# What is 'pointermove' event and why it takes so much time?

Tags: angular, angular-material

If you go to Angular material site, open any example and run perfomance in Chrome devtools -- you will see something like that:[image]

What is this? 700 ms of what? What should one do about? Ignore?

Comment: The pointermove event is a w3 specification: https://www.w3.org/TR/pointerevents/#the-pointermove-event

Comment: @ForestG, real question is what is taking 700 ms then? Why it always happen at start of Perfomance, but not later? Is it normal or not? Same thing in angularjs material examples page takes ~ 160 ms -- why it differs?

Answer (score 0):

My take is that you see **your own** mouse movement on the screen.

If I run the profiling, without my mouse touching the screen, there is no sign of that event:
[image]
In order to achive the same pattern as yours, I hade to move my pointer through the screen:
[image]

My take is, that you move the mouse over the screen, in order to click refresh, and you see that. The function call is- or is not- handled by the application, I think the change detection cycle is constantly being triggered upon mouse movement in Angular. Can you please check, if you can see the event if you do not hover over the screen?

The pointermove event is a w3 specification, fired by the browser: [w3.org/TR/pointerevents/#the-pointermove-event](http://w3.org/TR/pointerevents/#the-pointermove-event).